# Should we call $T \otimes_R S[[x]]$ just a Scalar extension?

Tags: number-theory, commutative-algebra, tensor-products

I am describing the following situation.

Let $R, S$ be two commutative rings such that $R \subset S$ and let $T$ be a finite flat $R$-algebra.

Define a module $M$ on the power series ring $S[[x]]$.

Now take an action of $T$ on $S[[x]]$ and assume that $M$ is a again module over the new ring $T \otimes_R S[[x]]$.

$(1)$ How do we describe the above situation ?

$(2)$ Is it just a scalar extension ?

$(3)$ Should we give an appropriate name depending on the action of $T$ ?

$(4)$ On the hand, if we define another  module $M'$ over the new ring $T \otimes_R S[[x]]$, then how should we   describe the whole procedure starting from $M$ to obtain $M'$ ?   what should we call it ?

Any comments on these $4$ questions are appreciated.